# Dlib rectangle width issue

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, dlib

I am using Dlib for object tracking with images/video.  I created a box using
`r=rectangle(4096,1195,4096,1419)`
It has created but when I check width it is giving '1'. But it should be 0 as left and right pixel are equal. So, it is not giving area as '0'. `r.width()` `r.area()`.
Is it issue with dlib (version: 19.21.1)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what it's supposed to do, the "area" is the number of pixels to which the rectangle is referencing.  See the documentation: http://dlib.net/dlib/geometry/rectangle_abstract.h.html

Comment: Okay, rectangle becomes a line as per dlib. Is there any provision for getting geometrical area from the rectangle object directly instead of calculating manually?

Comment: If that’s what you want then use the drectangle.